# WCF service on IIS hosted cant be connected with test web app on same server but from localhost can

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service which I hosted on IIS 7.5 on my web server and I build a simple web application to test my wcf service. I can connect and send request and get response when I run my test client on my localhost IIS express. my endpoint address is webserver address where my wcf is hosted but when I publish my test web app on the same server and try to do tests, I get no request and no response. nothing happens. test application doesnt have anything beside a button and a textbox. no javascript etc. I tried making it as a virtual app and standalone but no chance. what could be the problem?

here is how my webconfig looks like

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength ="8192"  />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="serviceBasicHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </basicHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <client>      
      <endpoint address="http://myservice.com/Service.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="serviceBasicHttpBinding"
          contract="serviceWCF.IService" name="serviceBasicHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: I would start from checking firewalls.

Comment: I checked it but It is supposed to use port 80 as default right? and It has no restriction. what kind of other checks should I do? thanks